# Calculate month on month growth rate of orders for the last 3 months for each country

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am trying to find the month on month growth rate of orders for the past 3 months for each country.
So far I have tried:

```
select date_part('month', order_date) as mnth,
country_id,
100 * (count() - lag(count(), 1) over (order by order_date)) / lag(count(), 1) over (order by order_date) as growth
from orders
and order_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
group by country_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

When we GROUP BY country_id, we produce a result of rows, one per country.

The aggregate COUNT will then operate on one group for each country and the subsequent window function (LAG) won't see more than one row for each country.

There's no way, in this context, LAG can be used to obtain data for a prior month for the same country.

`GROUP BY country_id, date_part('month', order_date)` is one approach that could be used. Be sure to LAG OVER PARTITIONs for each country, ordered by date.

Here's a small change in your SQL that might help (not tested and just a starting point).

Note: I used SQL Server to test below.  Convert `datepart` to `date_part` as needed.

[Fiddle for SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=5fbd8fe60c79cedd3941fda4a069b84c)

```sql
WITH cte AS (
        SELECT *, datepart(month, order_date) AS mnth
          FROM orders
         WHERE order_date >= DATEADD(DAY, -90, GETDATE())
     )
SELECT mnth
     , country_id
     , 100 * (COUNT(*) - LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY mnth)) / LAG(COUNT(*)) OVER (PARTITION BY country_id ORDER BY mnth) AS growth
  FROM cte
 GROUP BY country_id, mnth
;
```